# Llamar todos los objetos en memoria en r

Tags: r

Necesito correr una misma rutina a varios dataframe que están en la memoria de r, llamados data_1, data_2, etc. y no siempre serán la misma cantidad de archivos, así que lo que deseo es llamar a cada df uno a uno y correr la misma rutina a cada uno, con `l=ls(pattern="data")` he logrado listarlos sin embargo esta lista guarda solo los nombres como caracteres, así que si deseo realizar

`for (i in 1:length(l)) {
colnames(l[i])[colnames(l[i])=="Dirección"]="Gerencia"
}`

obviamente no corre el script porque lee cada l[i] como un carácter no como un objeto, de la misma forma si intento hacerlo con

```
matrix(data = l,ncol = length(l))
```

¿Como puedo llamar a todos estos df como objetos y poder correr esta u otras rutinas a la vez?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero veamos la solución "natural" y a mi criterio la óptima a este problema, cuya idea pasa por evitar el uso objetos individuales para cada `data.frame`, y manejar directamente una lista de objetos, dónde cada elemento de la lista será un `data.frame`. Por ejemplo:

```
lista_df <- list()
lista_df[[1]] <- mtcars[sample(1:nrow(mtcars),5),]
lista_df[[2]] <- mtcars[sample(1:nrow(mtcars),5),]
lista_df[[3]] <- mtcars[sample(1:nrow(mtcars),5),]

for (i in 1:length(lista_df)) {
  colnames(lista_df[[i]])[colnames(lista_df[[i]])=="mpg"]="millas/galon"
}
```

En este caso, en vez de crear objetos independientes tipo `data_1`, `data_2`, etc, creamos una lista única `lista_df` y vamos agregando cada objeto en ella. Podemos ahora sí acceder a cada elemento (y modificarlo) mediante un índice: `lista_df[[i]]`

Podrías incluso, siempre que dispongas de memoria, convertir todos tus objetos `data*`  en un lista como la que te comentaba antes, usando `mget()` para acceder al objeto por nombre:

```
lista_datos <- mget(ls(pattern="data"))
```

Lo que es importante entender, es que estás trabajando con copias de todos los objetos `data*` y la modificación del nombre de columna la haces sobre cada elemento  `lista_datos` y no sobre los `data*`, por lo cual a partir de este momento deberías seguir trabajando sobre `lista_datos`

Otra forma, que es más cercana a lo que buscas, es decir, modificar individualmente cada objeto es hacer lo siguiente:

```
data_1 <- mtcars[sample(1:nrow(mtcars),5),]
data_2 <- mtcars[sample(1:nrow(mtcars),5),]
data_3 <- mtcars[sample(1:nrow(mtcars),5),]

nombres <- ls(pattern="data")
for (objname in nombres) {
  df <- get(objname)
  colnames(df)[colnames(df)=="mpg"]="millas/galon"
  assign(objname, df)
}
```

En es este caso iteramos por cada nombre de objeto, obtenemos una copia temporal de dicho objeto mediante `get(objname)`, configuramos el nombre de las columnas del mismo y "pisamos" luego el objeto original con la nueva versión, mediante `assign(objname, df)`. Esta alternativa, yo sinceramente la descartaría, por que es mucho más fácil para muchas otras cosas, trabajar directamente con una lista, además que de esta forma, estamos "copiando" innecesariamente datos, con el consiguiente perjuicio en la performance y la eventual imposibilidad de poder hacer este proceso en caso de no poder alocar el espacio adicional al objeto temporal.

Comment: Finalmente tomé la última opción, iterar por cada objeto; al utilizar la primera opción (lista) me topé con el problema de llamar iterativamente a una columna específica del df, `lista[[1$v1]]` no puede utilizarse debido al error "$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors" puedo hacerlo mediante `lista[[data_1[,"v1"]]]` y funciona dando el nombre del df pero no en un for haciendo referencia a la **posición** del df dentro de la lista como esto `lista[[1[,"v1"]]]`